# Multiple aggregations of the same column using pandas GroupBy.agg()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Is there a pandas built-in way to apply two different aggregating functions `f1, f2` to the same column `df["returns"]`, without having to call `agg()` multiple times?

Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

pd.np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
         "date"    :  [dt.date(2012, x, 1) for x in range(1, 11)], 
         "returns" :  0.05 * np.random.randn(10), 
         "dummy"   :  np.repeat(1, 10)
})
```

The syntactically wrong, but intuitively right, way to do it would be:

```
# Assume `f1` and `f2` are defined for aggregating.
df.groupby("dummy").agg({"returns": f1, "returns": f2})
```

Obviously, Python doesn't allow duplicate keys. Is there any other manner for expressing the input to `agg()`? Perhaps a list of tuples `[(column, function)]` would work better, to allow multiple functions applied to the same column? But `agg()` seems like it only accepts a dictionary.

Is there a workaround for this besides defining an auxiliary function that just applies both of the functions inside of it? (How would this work with aggregation anyway?)

Comment: Related -[Aggregation in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53781634/2901002)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

As of 2022-06-20, the below is the accepted practice for aggregations:

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg(
    Mean=('returns', np.mean),
    Sum=('returns', np.sum))
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300159/4909087) for more information.

---

Below the fold included for historical versions of `pandas`.

You can simply pass the functions as a list:

```
In [20]: df.groupby("dummy").agg({"returns": [np.mean, np.sum]})
Out[20]:         
           mean       sum
dummy                    
1      0.036901  0.369012
```

or as a dictionary:

```
In [21]: df.groupby('dummy').agg({'returns':
                                  {'Mean': np.mean, 'Sum': np.sum}})
Out[21]: 
        returns          
           Mean       Sum
dummy                    
1      0.036901  0.369012
```

Comment: 1st one works fine, 2nd one dones't : SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Answer (score 249):

TLDR; Pandas `groupby.agg` has a new, easier syntax for specifying (1) aggregations on multiple columns, and (2) multiple aggregations on a column. So, to do this for **pandas >= 0.25**, use

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg(Mean=('returns', 'mean'), Sum=('returns', 'sum'))

           Mean       Sum
dummy                    
1      0.036901  0.369012
```

OR

```
df.groupby('dummy')['returns'].agg(Mean='mean', Sum='sum')

           Mean       Sum
dummy                    
1      0.036901  0.369012
```

---

## Pandas >= 0.25: [Named Aggregation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

Pandas has changed the behavior of `GroupBy.agg` in favour of a more intuitive syntax for specifying named aggregations. See the [0.25 docs section on Enhancements](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#enhancements) as well as relevant GitHub issues [GH18366](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18366) and [GH26512](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26512).

From the documentation,

> To support column-specific aggregation with control over the output
>   column names, pandas accepts the special syntax in `GroupBy.agg()`,
>   known as “named aggregation”, where
>
> - The keywords are the output column names
> - The values are tuples whose first element is the column to select and the second element is the aggregation to apply to that column.
>     Pandas provides the pandas.NamedAgg namedtuple with the fields
>     ['column', 'aggfunc'] to make it clearer what the arguments are. As
>     usual, the aggregation can be a callable or a string alias.

You can now pass a tuple via keyword arguments. The tuples follow the format of `(<colName>, <aggFunc>)`.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__                                                                                                                            
# '0.25.0.dev0+840.g989f912ee'

# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
                   'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
                   'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0]
})

df.groupby('kind').agg(
    max_height=('height', 'max'), min_weight=('weight', 'min'),)

      max_height  min_weight
kind                        
cat          9.5         7.9
dog         34.0         7.5
```

Alternatively, you can use `pd.NamedAgg` (essentially a namedtuple) which makes things more explicit.

```
df.groupby('kind').agg(
    max_height=pd.NamedAgg(column='height', aggfunc='max'), 
    min_weight=pd.NamedAgg(column='weight', aggfunc='min')
)

      max_height  min_weight
kind                        
cat          9.5         7.9
dog         34.0         7.5
```

It is even simpler for Series, just pass the aggfunc to a keyword argument.

```
df.groupby('kind')['height'].agg(max_height='max', min_height='min')    

      max_height  min_height
kind                        
cat          9.5         9.1
dog         34.0         6.0
```

Lastly, if your column names aren't valid python identifiers, use a dictionary with unpacking:

```
df.groupby('kind')['height'].agg(**{'max height': 'max', ...})
```

---

## Pandas < 0.25

In more recent versions of pandas leading upto 0.24, if using a dictionary for specifying column names for the aggregation output, you will get a `FutureWarning`:

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg({'returns': {'Mean': 'mean', 'Sum': 'sum'}})
# FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed 
# in a future version
```

[Using a dictionary for renaming columns is deprecated in v0.20.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming) On more recent versions of pandas, this can be specified more simply by passing a list of tuples. If specifying the functions this way, *all* functions for that column need to be specified as tuples of (name, function) pairs.

```
df.groupby("dummy").agg({'returns': [('op1', 'sum'), ('op2', 'mean')]})

        returns          
            op1       op2
dummy                    
1      0.328953  0.032895
```

Or,

```
df.groupby("dummy")['returns'].agg([('op1', 'sum'), ('op2', 'mean')])

            op1       op2
dummy                    
1      0.328953  0.032895
```

Comment: Am I the only one who finds the new syntax MUCH WORSE than the dict? There's another crucial difference: with dict, the column names show up in the returned DataFrame (see above, the first example with dict has 'returns' as extra column index level, while the second example does not. How do I get those column names back?!?

Answer (score 7):

Would something like this work:

```
In [7]: df.groupby('dummy').returns.agg({'func1' : lambda x: x.sum(), 'func2' : lambda x: x.prod()})
Out[7]: 
              func2     func1
dummy                        
1     -4.263768e-16 -0.188565
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns that you need to apply the same multiple aggregation functions on, the simplest way (imo) is to use a dictionary comprehension.

```py
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy': [0, 1, 1], 'A': range(3), 'B':range(1, 4), 'C':range(2, 5)})

# aggregation
df.groupby("dummy").agg({k: ['sum', 'mean'] for k in ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

[image: multiindex]

The above results in a dataframe with MultiIndex column. If a flat custom column names are desired, named aggregation is the way to go (as suggested in the other answers on here).

As [stated in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation), the keys should be the output column names and the values should be tuples `(column, aggregation function)` for named aggregations. Since there are multiple columns and multiple functions, this results in a nested structure. To flatten it into a single dictionary, you can either use `collections.ChainMap()` or a nested loop.

Also, if you prefer the grouper column (`dummy`) as a column (not index), specify `as_index=False` in `groupby()`.

```py
from collections import ChainMap
# convert a list of dictionaries into a dictionary
dct = dict(ChainMap(*reversed([{f'{k}_total': (k, 'sum'), f'{k}_mean': (k, 'mean')} for k in ['A','B','C']])))
# {'A_total': ('A', 'sum'), 'A_avg': ('A', 'mean'), 'B_total': ('B', 'sum'), 'B_avg': ('B', 'mean'), 'C_total': ('C', 'sum'), 'C_avg': ('C', 'mean')}

# the same result obtained by a nested loop
# dct = {k:v for k in ['A','B','C'] for k,v in [(f'{k}_total', (k, 'sum')), (f'{k}_avg', (k, 'mean'))]}

# aggregation
df.groupby('dummy', as_index=False).agg(**dct)
```

[image: flat]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a lambda within a NamedAggregation

```
df.groupby('dummy').returns.agg({
  'summed' : pd.NamedAgg(column='date', aggfunc=lambda series: sum(series.values()),
  'joined' : pd.NamedAgg(column='returns', aggfunc=lambda series: ','.join(series.values())),
})
```