# groupby with aggregate method in Python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

```
count =dataframe[dataframe["Type"]=="h"].sort_values("Date",ascending=False).groupby("Date").count()

mean = dataframe[dataframe["Type"]=="h"].sort_values("Date",ascending=False).groupby("Date").mean()

var = dataframe[dataframe["Type"]=="h"].sort_values("Date", ascending=False).groupby("Date").std()
```

dataframe is a `pandas` dataframe. count and mean are working but outputting `var` shows the following error:
`InvalidOperation:` []

Comment: what is the `datatype` of `Date` ?

Comment: @ksai datetime64

Comment: Can you find the `std()` of `datetime64`

Comment: @ksai It is just grouping by date. std() operator is for the columns of the dataframe which are numeric.

Comment: Can you provide the dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589481/python-pandas-multiple-aggregations-of-the-same-column this might be something you're looking for.

Comment: try `yourdf.describe()` function. This might be a good option too!

Comment: Can you try to convert the date into their exact millisecond value and then try to apply those functions !! Beause witb My knowledge i know it only works why numerical values not dates