# Using multiple lambda functions with a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pd data frame in which the column called "process_id" has, for multiple time steps, different parameters associated with it. I want to extract several information from these and put them into a new data frame (so I don't have to use all the details of the data). Below is an example of what I mean, where I keep, for each "process_id" the min, max, mean and std of each parameter and I also define a lambda function to save the mean of the parameters in the last 5 timesteps:

```
features = df.groupby('process_id').agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', lambda x: x.tail(5).mean()])
```

This works fine and the lambda function changes the name of the parameter in the table to something like this: "parameter_lambda" (not sure how, but it works). Now the problem is that if I want to add another lambda function, something like this (or any other lambda definition):

```
features = df.groupby('process_id').agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', lambda x: x.tail(5).mean(),lambda x: x.iloc[0:int(len(df)/5)].mean()])
```

I get this error:

> Function names must be unique, found multiple named

Which makes sense, as both lambda functions will have the same name in the data frame. But I don't know how to get around this.

I tried something like this:

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg({'returns':{'Mean': np.mean, 'Sum': np.sum}})
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589481/multiple-aggregations-of-the-same-column-using-pandas-groupby-agg), but I am getting this error:

> SpecificationError: cannot perform renaming for returns with a nested
>   dictionary

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please include an [mcve]

Comment: I'm inclined to think of this as a bug in pandas, if it accepts functions but relies on the `__name__` attribute to distinguish them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lambda` function will have the problem with duplicate name errors when there are more than one para created by `lambda`

```
fuc1=lambda x: x.tail(5).mean()
fuc1.__name__ = 'tail_mean'

fuc2=lambda x: x.iloc[0:int(len(df)/5)].mean()
fuc2.__name__ = 'len_mean'

features = df.groupby('process_id').agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', fuc1,fuc2])
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BillKet yw :-) btw if it is what you need , would like accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
features = df.groupby('process_id').agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', lambda x: x.tail(5).mean(),lambda y: y.iloc[0:int(len(df)/5)].mean()])
```

Try with `x` and `y` instead of `x` and `x`

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg({'returns': [np.mean, np.sum]})
```

Also, try this

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting the same error. The name comes purely from "lambda". It doesn't contain the variable in it.

Comment: I think @Wen-Ben 's answer might be it. I learnt something new too