# rename results in data frame pandas

Tags: pandas

in pandas data frame it try to make some statistical analysis on column (heart rate) it aggregate with patient id and hour of measure, then make all statistical analysis

> (mean,max,etc)

, my question is how to rename the return result ( to name **sum_heart_rate** instead of **sum,** **min_heart_rate** instead of **min** )
as follows

```
newdataframe= df2.groupby(['DayHour','subject_id']).agg({"Heart Rate":['sum' ,'min','max','std', 'count','var','skew']})
```

Comment: you can also add a `.rename(columns={})` and pass dict values to your col names. also a sample of your dataframe column names would be ideal to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below template. You add more columns if needed.

```
newdataframe= (df2.groupby(['DayHour','subject_id']).agg(sum_heart_rate =('heart rate', 'sum'), min_heart_rate =('heart rate','min'))
```

For pandas version below 0.25 use code below

```
newdataframe = df2.groupby('date')['heart rate'].agg([('sum_heart_rate','sum'), ('min_heart_rate','min')])
```

Comment: i think this exactly what i want, but when i try it , it return this error   "aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'"   @moys

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821579/pandas-groupby-agg-throws-typeerror-aggregate-missing-1-required-positional if your pandas version is lower than 0.25, you will have to do it a bit differently.