# Use groupby.sum() on dataframe with mixed int and string python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe containg text and some value counts e.g.:

```
dates=['01-01-15','01-01-15','01-01-15','02-01-15','02-01-15','02-01-15','02-01-15']
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':['001','001','001','002','002','002','002'],
                   'name':['peter','chris','meg','albert','cathrine','leo','leo'],
                   'dummy':[0,1,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'dates': dates})
df3.dates=pd.to_datetime(df3.dates)
```

Now i want to group it by the "Number" column and sum, so that the values will be summed and the text will become one list with all entries, and each group will have one date.

If i use `df4=pd.DataFrame(df3.groupby('Number').sum())` it performs the necessary operations on the numeric data, but loses the text and date column.

So the output shold look like:

```
df4
Number      name                   dummy    dates
001     [peter,chris,meg]            1    01-01-15
002     [albert, cathrine, leo,leo]  2    02-01-15
```

Comment: Related: Named aggregations as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300159)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `.agg` to specify multiple aggregation functions, like `list`, `sum` and `first`:

```
df3.groupby('Number', as_index=False).agg({'name':list,
                                           'dummy':'sum',
                                           'dates':'first'})
```

**Output**

```
  Number                          name  dummy      dates
0    001           [peter, chris, meg]      1 2015-01-01
1    002  [albert, cathrine, leo, leo]      2 2015-02-01
```

---

#### Pandas version >= 0.25

Since verison 0.25 we are moving away from the dictionary and using tuples instead.

*See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling)*

```
df3.groupby('Number', as_index=False).agg(name_list=('name',list),
                                          dummy_sum=('dummy','sum'),
                                          dates=('dates','first'))
```

**Output**

```
                      name_list  dummy_sum      dates
0           [peter, chris, meg]          1 2015-01-01
1  [albert, cathrine, leo, leo]          2 2015-02-01
```

Comment: ah this works perfectly, but do i have to specify the function for each single column? because on my real dataframe i have 30 columns for most of which i have to sum the data

Comment: No you dont have to, you can split your dataframe and only keep the `Number` column and all the rest which you want to sum and just use `df3.groupby('Number').sum()`. After that join it back with your categorical data. @user11638654.