# pandas - aggregate count per month and calculate total sum of counts afterwards

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For my dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                   'Month': ['Feb', 'March', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March', 'May']})
```

I want to aggregate a data set by ID and its month so I get the counts per month and the total sum over all periods:

```
ID Month
1   Feb
1   March
2   Feb
2   Feb
2   March
2   March
3   May
```

I need following output:

```
ID Month  count total_sum
1  Feb    1     2
1  Marc   1     2
2  Feb    2     4
2  March  2     4
3  May    1     1
```

Comment: It looks like you want a groupby (in your case you would groupby ["ID","Month"] with a couple functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589481/multiple-aggregations-of-the-same-column-using-pandas-groupby-agg

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` twice, once by `['ID', 'Month']` and then by `'ID'` to count per month per ID and total count per ID, respectively.

Note that in the first `groupby` is the case where you use `count` method but in the second `groupby` you use `sum` method because you're aggregating the counts.

```
out = df.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).agg(count=('ID','count')).reset_index()
out['total count'] = out.groupby('ID')['count'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Month  count  total count
0   1    Feb      1            2
1   1  March      1            2
2   2    Feb      2            4
3   2  March      2            4
4   3    May      1            1
```

Comment: @KostaS. was your question not resolved?