# pivot_table(), multiple aggfuncs to the *same* column - possible?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

EDIT - please don't lock this question, the similar question links do not provide answers as my question is for applying multiple aggfuncs to the *same* value column.

I have a standard pivot_table() function being applied to a dataframe in the following way:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Month'], values=['Claims', 'Policy Holdings'], aggfunc={'Claims': 'min', 'Policy Holdings': 'max'})
```

I'm interested to know, say that I want to use the same column in my values twice, with a different aggfunc (i.e. min and max) - is this possible?

The following code doesn't work:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Month'], values=['Claims', 'Claims'], aggfunc={'Claims': 'min', 'Claims': 'max'})
```

Of course I could make a copy of the column beforehand with a different name but I imagine there's a more elegant solution available?

Comment: `Groupby` then `agg` and `pivot_table` are pretty similar. You can find useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12589481/15239951)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Year', 'Month'], values=['Claims'], aggfunc={'Claims': ['min','max']})
```