# Group by columns under conditions to calculate average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a *raw* dataset like below:

| ColA | ColB | duration | interval | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | SD | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| A | SD | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| A | UD | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| B | UD | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| B | UD | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| B | SD | 3 | 3 | 13 |
| B | SD | 1 | 4 | 19 |

I am expecting an *output result* like below:

[image]

**Explanation of the output:**

1. SumCounter is the sum of counter values on the group by ColA and ColB values.
2. AvgdurationSD/UD and AvgIntervalSD/UD are created by taking the average over ColA and ColB and having a 0 value incase the columns dont match the criteria (e.g. AvgDurationSD and AvIntervalSD has 0 value for a group of ColA = A and ColB = UD.

I understand that I have to use `group by` and `agg` functions to apply here but I am not really sure how to apply conditions for ColB on individual new columns.

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with helper column `new` by copy like `ColB`, then flatten `MultiIndex` and add ouput to new DataFrame created by aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new=df['ColB'])
         .pivot_table(index=['ColA', 'ColB'], 
                      columns='new', 
                      values=['interval','duration'], 
                      fill_value=0,
                      aggfunc='mean'))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df = (df.groupby(['ColA','ColB'])['Counter']
        .sum()
        .to_frame(name='SumCounter')
        .join(df1).reset_index())
print (df)
  ColA ColB  SumCounter  durationSD  durationUD  intervalSD  intervalUD
0    A   SD           3         2.5         0.0         3.5           0
1    A   UD          10         0.0         2.0         0.0           1
2    B   SD          32         2.0         0.0         3.5           0
3    B   UD           4         0.0         1.5         0.0           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try group by column `A` and group by column `B` with [`Named Aggregation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300159/10315163)

```py
out = df.groupby('ColA').apply(lambda g: g.groupby('ColB').agg({'duration': [(f'{g["ColB"].iloc[0]}', 'mean')],
                                                                'interval': [(f'{g["ColB"].iloc[0]}', 'mean')],
                                                                'Counter': 'sum'})).fillna(0)
```

```
print(out)

          duration interval Counter duration interval
                SD       SD     sum       UD       UD
ColA ColB
A    SD        2.5      3.5       3      0.0      0.0
     UD        2.0      1.0      10      0.0      0.0
B    SD        0.0      0.0      32      2.0      3.5
     UD        0.0      0.0       4      1.5      2.0
```

Then rename the multi index column

```py
out.columns = ['SumCounter' if 'Counter' in col[0] else f'Avg{col[0]}{col[1]}' for col in out.columns.values]
```

```
print(out)

           AvgdurationSD  AvgintervalSD  SumCounter  AvgdurationUD  AvgintervalUD
ColA ColB
A    SD              2.5            3.5           3            0.0            0.0
     UD              2.0            1.0          10            0.0            0.0
B    SD              0.0            0.0          32            2.0            3.5
     UD              0.0            0.0           4            1.5            2.0
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting solution, never seen before. Unfortunately I am afraid about performance, because `groupby` is slow, so I think nested groupby should be `super slow`.

Answer (score 0):

One option with groupby:

```py
temp = (df
        .assign(dummy = df.ColB)
        .groupby(['ColA','ColB','dummy'])
        .agg({'duration':'mean', 'interval':'mean', 'Counter':'sum'})
        .rename(columns = {'Counter':'SumCounter'})
        .set_index('SumCounter', append = True)
        .unstack('dummy', fill_value = 0)
        )

temp.columns = temp.columns.map(lambda x: f"Avg{''.join(x)}")

temp.reset_index()

  ColA ColB  SumCounter  AvgdurationSD  AvgdurationUD  AvgintervalSD  AvgintervalUD
0    A   SD           3            2.5            0.0            3.5            0.0
1    A   UD          10            0.0            2.0            0.0            1.0
2    B   SD          32            2.0            0.0            3.5            0.0
3    B   UD           4            0.0            1.5            0.0            2.0
```